# What does the miniature planet do in dungreed?

Tags: dungreed

I got it and I can equip it but it doesn't do anything. Is there a hidden use for it or just a nice accessory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the miniature planet equipped along with 3 other accessories that rotate around you, it provides bonuses to each along with it's own bonus.

[image]